# How to call a vuejs method after 500ms

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a searching method, which calls ajax in each keyup, but I want It calls after 500ms when I start typing, Please suggest to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) from [lodash](https://lodash.com/), a sample implementation looks like this:

```
<input v-on:keyup="debounceInput">

import _ from 'lodash'
....
methods: {
  debounceInput: _.debounce(function (e) {
    //Your code here
  }, 500)
}
```

Using debounce from lodash is suggested in vue.js [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#debounce-Param-Attribute-for-v-model-removed) as well.

You can also use  [debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce) NPM package, above example will look like following with debounce:

```
<input v-on:keyup="debounceInput">

import debounce from 'debounce'
....

methods: {
  debounceInput: debounce(function (e) {
    //Your code here
  }, 500)
}
```